# How to use display:none to remove element?

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the element that is high lighted in blue on the below screenshot.

If I add the following to the CSS

```
#p-tb body, { display:none }
```

it is still not removed.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can't remove elements from the DOM using CSS; it's a common misconception that `display: none` removes elements from the DOM. You need to tell us what exactly you mean by "removing" the element.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but I notice an unrelated problem in your code that I thought I'd point out... you have a style tag between your closing /head and opening body tags. There shouldn't be anything between the head and the body so that style tag should be moved elsewhere (preferably into the head).

Comment: @redlena Very interesting. It is MediaWiki 1.18.2 that we are looking at in the screenshot =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#p-tb .body` is the selector you need - you missed the `.` and have an extra `,` freeloading on the end.

EDIT: Although, even if you correct that, the inline style will override that rule, except maybe if you add `!important` after the `display:none`.

Comment: +1 And it's very clearly seen that the style is not applied .... (`display: block;` is the only `display` applied, inherited or shadowed or whatnot)

Comment: `#p-tb .body { display:none !important}` did the trick. What does `!important` do?

Comment: `!important` gives the property unusually high precedence. Normally inline `style="..."` attributes have higher precedence than any stylesheet will allow, but the `!important` overrides even that. That said, `!important` is usually seen a sign of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Display:none only hides the element. You can't remove an element via CSS.

Use javascript instead!

Comment: "hide" == "remove... from view"

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using `display: none;` on elements that can contain text. You could find yourself getting into SEO problems.